# Swift error comparing two arrays of optionals

Tags: swift

I get a **compilation error** in the next Swift code

```
var x:Array<Int?> = [1,2]
var y:Array<Int?> = [1,2]
if x == y {  // Error
}
```

If both arrays are `Array<Int>` it works fine, but if at least one of them is optional it throws an error like the next:

> Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two `Array<Int?>` operands

I filed a bug report months ago but I had no answer. It still occurs in Swift 1.2.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Int? is not an Int which can be `nil`, it is an optional which can be Int when not `nil`. So, Int and Int? are different types which can't be compared.

Comment: I also filed several bugs with Swift, also months ago, and also no feedback. I made a calculation that Apple gets about 9500 bug reports on radar per day. So they probably work by the (high) numbers...

Comment: @sasquatch what you say is true but not really the root cause.  There are no non-optionals here, the problem is the lack of `Equatable` conformance of optionals.

Comment: @sasquatch you're mostly right, but you can actually compare `Int` and `Int?` (I just tried it). That's what was confusing me.

Comment: yeah, @AirspeedVelocity's answer is most precise. Upvoted

Comment: @sangonz strictly speaking, when you compare an `Int` to an `Int?` what is happening is Swift is implicitly wrapping the non-optional in an optional and then comparing two `Int?`s…  see [this article](http://airspeedvelocity.net/2015/01/02/more-fun-with-implicitly-wrapped-non-optionals/) for more on this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue here is the distinction between something having an `==` operator, versus something being “equatable”.

Both `Optional` and `Array` have an `==` operator, that works when what they contain is equatable:

```
// if T is equatable, you can compare each entry for equality
func ==<T : Equatable>(lhs: [T], rhs: [T]) -> Bool
// if T is equatable, you can compare the contents, if any, for equality
func ==<T : Equatable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool

let i: Int? = 1
let j: Int = 1
i == j          // fine, Int is Equatable
["a","b"] == ["a","b"]  // and so is String
```

But they themselves do not conform to `Equatable`.  This makes sense given you can put a non-equatable type inside them.  But the upshot of this is, if an array contains a non-equatable type, then `==` won’t work.  And since optionals aren’t `Equatable`, this is the case when you put an optional in an array.

You'd get the same thing if you tried to compare an array of arrays:

```
let a = [[1,2]]
let b = [[1,2]]
a == b  // error: `==` can’t be applied to `[Array<Int>]`
```

If you wanted to special case it, you could write `==` for arrays of optionals as:

```
func ==<T: Equatable>(lhs: [T?], rhs: [T?]) -> Bool {
    if lhs.count != rhs.count { return false }
    for (l,r) in zip(lhs,rhs) {
        if l != r { return false }
    }
    return true
}
```

For a counter-example, since `Set` requires its contents to be hashable (and thus equatable), it *can* be equatable:

```
let setarray: [Set<Int>] = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
setarray == [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]  // true
```

Comment: I'm confused: the second implementation of == what you pasted here, doesn't it suggest, that if I have two arrays with the type [Int]?, than you can compare them? But actually it fails and force you to unwrap them.

Comment: @DánielNagy the `==` is the signature for the version of `==` for optionals.  But just because optionals have an `==` operator does _not_ mean they are `Equatable`.  To conform to `Equatable`, the type needs an unqualified `==` operator, whereas the optional version only applies to optionals that contain an equatable type (what would it do if the contained type weren’t equatable?).   Unfortunately I can’t paste nonexistent code to show this :-)

Comment: That's exactly what I was missing. I assumed that last function in the answer was already implemented in Swift. Thanks!

Comment: Here's another formulation of the == implementation inspired by the Protocol-Oriented Programming talk from WWDC 2015: `return lhs.count == rhs.count && !zip(lhs, rhs).contains { $0 != $1 }`