# Comparing optional arrays

Tags: swift

Running the following code snippet in the playground gives an error:

```
let a: [Int]? = [1,2]
let b: [Int]? = [1,2]
a == b // value of optional type '[Int]?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
```

While doing something similar for a 'simpler' optional type works:

```
var x: Int? = 10
var y: Int?
x == y // false
```

What is the reasoning behind the first case, of optional arrays, not being allowed? Why can't Swift first see if either side if `nil` (`.None`) and then if they are not, do the actual array comparison.

Comment: What version of Swift are you using? Your second case gives me an error of `Variable 'y' used before being initialized`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift error comparing two arrays of optionals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28830411/swift-error-comparing-two-arrays-of-optionals)

Comment: Sorry, i was typing this over from a playground. Corrected the question.

Comment: @milo526 not a duplicate. this is about optional arrays, not arrays of optionals :-)

Comment: The answer amounts to the same thing... neither arrays nor optionals are equatable, so the version of `==` that work when they contain equatable things don't work on them...

Comment: But I agree, it's a different question (the code to implement `==` is very different)

Answer (score 31):

The reason it works for simpler types is because there is a version of `==` that is defined for optionals that contain types that are `Equatable`:

```
func ==<T : Equatable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool
```

But while `Int` is `Equatable`, `Array` is not (because it might contain something that is not equatable - in which case how could it be).  All `Equatable` things have an `==` operator, but not all things with an `==` operator are `Equatable`.

You could write a special-case version of `==` specifically for optional arrays containing equatable types:

```
func ==<T: Equatable>(lhs: [T]?, rhs: [T]?) -> Bool {
    switch (lhs,rhs) {
    case (.Some(let lhs), .Some(let rhs)):
        return lhs == rhs
    case (.None, .None):
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}
```

You could also generalize this to cover any collection containing equatable elements:

```
func ==<C: CollectionType where C.Generator.Element: Equatable>
  (lhs: C?, rhs: C?) -> Bool {
    switch (lhs,rhs) {
    case (.Some(let lhs), .Some(let rhs)):
        return lhs == rhs
    case (.None, .None):
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Could there be any reason why Apple didn't implemented it directly ?

Comment: Also I'm having troubles with the second func you proposed. When comparing [String]? to nil, the compiler returns `ambigous use of operator ==`. I would suggest only using the first one.

Comment: But why is the swift compiler able to resolve this: `Optional([1]) == Optional([1])`

Comment: @benrudhart I think that might be a bug (maybe only in older compilers?) where the compiler implicitly converts `[1]` to an `UnsafePointer<Int>` (for ease of C interop purposes), which is an `Equatable` type. In which case it isn't really comparing the arrays, just comparing if they happen to be backed be the same pointer after conversion (which in the case of two literals, they might be).

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity This actually runs in the current Xcode (7.2.1). You're probably right - so thank you! Still I don't get why the above mentioned inline comparison is treated different (compiles) than the following code

```let array1 = Optional([1]);
let array2 = Optional([1]);
array1 == array2 // throws error as expected``` (Sorry for using `;` here, Stackoverflow won't break lines in comments.)

Comment: For some reason this implementation recurses and causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS to me .(

Comment: Seems like we should be able to turn this into an extension of Array, but when I try I get "error: member operator '==' must have at least one argument of type 'Array<Element>'". Anyone else figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 8):

adding swift 3 version of Airspeed's answer:

```
func ==<T: Equatable>(lhs: [T]?, rhs: [T]?) -> Bool {
  switch (lhs,rhs) {
  case (.some(let lhs), .some(let rhs)):
    return lhs == rhs
  case (.none, .none):
    return true
  default:
    return false
  }
}

func ==<C: Collection where C.Iterator.Element: Equatable>(lhs: C?, rhs: C?) -> Bool {
  switch (lhs,rhs) {
  case (.some(let lhs), .some(let rhs)):
    return lhs == rhs
  case (.none, .none):
    return true
  default:
    return false
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

## Swift 4.1

**Update:** The missing functionality has been implemented in Swift 4.1.

Your code

```
let a: [Int]? = [1,2]
let b: [Int]? = [1,2]
a == b
```

compiles and works as expected since Xcode 9.3 (Swift 4.1).

### Old answer

The easiest is not to use optional array and use an empty array (`[]`) instead of `nil` - in case you don't need to distinguish between those two cases.

```
let a = [1,2]
let b = [1,2]
let c = []
a == b
b != c
```

It worked in my case when I was writing Equatable extension for a struct. Instead of using property `categories: [Category]?` I have just changed it to `categories: [Category]` and parsed missing categories as empty array (`[]`).