# How can I extend Array so equality check of arrays of optionals are possible?

Tags: arrays, swift, types, equality, xctest

I want to unit-test some code that creates values with types of the form `[T?]` (arrays of optionals). But `==` is not defined for arrays of optionals:

```
Binary Operator '==' cannot be applied to two '[String?]' operands
```

So I extend `Array` accordingly (following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28830767/539599)):

```
extension Array {
    static func ==<T: Equatable>(lhs: [T?], rhs: [T?]) -> Bool {
        if lhs.count != rhs.count {
            return false
        }
        else {
            return zip(lhs,rhs).reduce(true) { $0 && ($1.0 == $1.1) }
        }
    }
}
```

But now I get:

```
Ambiguous reference to member '=='
```

In combination, the messages don't seem to make sense; how can I go from zero fitting methods/functions to more than one?

How can I extend `Array` for checking equality of arrays of optionals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep it as an extension to Array:

```
extension Array where Element : Equatable {
    static func ==(lhs: [Element?], rhs: [Element?]) -> Bool {
        if lhs.count != rhs.count {
            return false
        }
        else {
            for i in 0..<lhs.count {
                if lhs[i] != rhs[i] { return false }
            }
            return true
        }
    }
}

let a: [String?] = ["John", nil]
let b: [String?] = ["John", nil]
let c: [String?] = ["Jack", nil]

print(a == b) // true
print(a == c) // false
```

The `for` loop here is more efficient for 2 reasons: (a) you don't have to construct a temporary array of tuples like with `zip` and (b) it returns `false` as soon as a non-match is found.

Comment: I don't care about the `for`-loop at all. How is the rest different from what I've done, except that you put the type parameter (bound) somewhere else? Why does that make a difference?

Comment: Because you were confusing between the generic parameter to the function and that to the `Array` struct. Your function has a generic parameter called `T`. `Array` has a generic parameter called `Element`. These two do not mix.

Comment: Apparently so... I still don't fully understand why. Why does it matter for this method whether the type parameter is `Element`? Does the binder not match the types properly? It still *should* find my definition as one that matches, intuitively speaking. Huh. (I note that one shouldn't trust Xcode. Nowhere does it say that `Array` is a generic or what it's type parameter's name was. I *was* wondering how things were implemented, but one can't look into the sources either...)

Comment: The Foundation framework is [open-sourced](https://github.com/apple/swift) but digging there is not fun either. You should always start with the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array)

Comment: Regarding `zip`, when programming functional style, chaining operators can lead to more efficient code than many loops. I don't think you can embed `==` into such a chain, though, so in this case I was using it more out of tinkeriness, less because of efficiency concerns.

Comment: Nota bene: the way from here to making arrays of optionals properly `Equatable` is syntactically short and seems to be [scheduled for implementation](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#conditional-conformances-), or at least on some developer's radar.